# Declare vector ports without specifying their size in Verilog

Tags: verilog

When declaring a module in Verilog (2001?), is it possible to tell that some ports are vectors without indicating their size? The goal here is to handle vector ports of any size, **without having to specify the sizes through parameters**.

I know I can write something like what follows in Verilog, but I'd like to know if there's a way to get rid of the extra `WIDTH_DATA` parameter:

```
module my_module
#(
  parameter  WIDTH_DATA = 48
)
(
  input  Clk, En,
  input  [WIDTH_DATA-1:0] Data_in,
  output Ready,
  output reg [WIDTH_DATA-1:0] Data_out
);
```

This is possible in VHDL, using a declaration like that:

```vhdl
entity my_module is
  port (
    Clk      : in std_ulogic;
    En       : in std_ulogic;
    Data_in  : in std_ulogic_vector;
    Ready    : out std_ulogic;
    Data_out : out std_ulogic_vector
  );
end entity;
```

The module implementation can then know the size of `Data_in` at compile time using `Data_in'length` (same for `Data_out`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in Verilog.

You can do something close to what you want in SystemVerilog using the `interface` construct. You can parameterize an interface, and connect that interface (or set of interfaces) to `my_module`.

```
interface my_intf #(int WIDTH);
  logic [WIDTH-1:0] data;
endinterface
module my_module(input clk, en,
                 my_intf in, out,
                 output ready);
  // $bits(in.data) - gives you the WIDTH
  // typedef type(out.data)  out_type // local typedef 
endmodule
module top;
  my_intf #(8) I1;
  my_intf #(16) I2;
  bit clk, en, ready;
  my_module M1 (.clk,.en, .in(I1), .out(I2), .ready);
endmodule
```